# Add Profile 2 -> Field Colleciton -> Taxonomoy into Facet (Search API)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I'm trying to display a Facet block , which uses Term reference (Taxonomy) of Field Collection of Profile 2. Since I am new to Search (API), I have tried all sort of things but nothing worked.

For example:

- Use Facet display of View: Rendered entity, Field..
- Use Facet Block from Search API
- Config options in Search /Search API..

In 
*Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » Search API » View index*

I added Facets the followings:

- Vocabulary: Facet blocks look good in the picture below
- Profile2->Field Collection: look good in the picture below
- Profile2->Field Collection->Vocabulary(Taxonomy): bad,It always shows empty

---

### [image: Search API of Field collection]

**My Question is:**

How can I make this happen? or Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution from Search API Drupal Recruiter  [here](https://drupal.org/project/recruiter)

In short, I have to click "+Add index" to make a new index based **Profile**

---

For example, Please take a look at the picture below to understand how to solve this issue.
[image]